# Multiple resolutions for HLS transcoding using FFMPEG in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I working on a node js project to convert uploaded mp4 files to HLS format (.m3u8) using FFMPEG.

I've developed a function like this,

```js
ffmpeg('test.mp4', { timeout: 432000 })
  .addOptions([
      "-profile:v baseline",
      "-level 3.0",
      "-start_number 0",
      "-hls_time 10",
      "-hls_list_size 0",
      "-master_pl_name master.m3u8",
      "-f hls"
  ])
  .output("videos/output.m3u8")
```

**Question:** This function is working as expected. But now I want the video to be transcoded in multiple formats in 360, 480, 720 and 1080 and expect an output of .m3u8 master file somewhat like

```html
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=72000,CODECS="mp4a.40.5"
output_64k_audio.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=620000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4d001e,mp4a.40.2"
output_360.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=812000,RESOLUTION=854x480,CODECS="avc1.4d001e,mp4a.40.2"
output_480.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1272000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
output_720.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1627000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.4d0028,mp4a.40.2"
output_1080.m3u8
```

Please help me with a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a package [simple-hls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-hls) which solves this issue,

here is the final solution:

```js
const { Transcoder } = require('simple-hls');

const customRenditions = (name) => {
    return [
        {
            width: 640,
            height: 360,
            profile: 'main',
            hlsTime: '10',
            bv: '800k',
            maxrate: '856k',
            bufsize: '1200k',
            ba: '96k',
            ts_title: `${name}_360p`,
            master_title: `${name}_360p`
        },
        {
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            profile: 'main',
            hlsTime: '10',
            bv: '1400k',
            maxrate: '1498',
            bufsize: '2100k',
            ba: '128k',
            ts_title: `${name}_480p`,
            master_title: `${name}_480p`
        },
        {
            width: 1280,
            height: 720,
            profile: 'main',
            hlsTime: '10',
            bv: '2800k',
            maxrate: '2996k',
            bufsize: '4200k',
            ba: '128k',
            ts_title: `${name}_720p`,
            master_title: `${name}_720p`
        },
        {
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080,
            profile: 'main',
            hlsTime: '10',
            bv: '5000k',
            maxrate: '5350k',
            bufsize: '7500k',
            ba: '192k',
            ts_title: `${name}_1080p`,
            master_title: `${name}_1080p`
        }
    ]
};

 try {
      const transcode = new Transcoder(newFileName, fileDestFolder + '/', { renditions: customRenditions(fileName), showLogs: false });
      transcode.transcode();
      console.log('Successfully Transcoded Video');
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Something went wrong : ' + e);
  }
```

Note that this package requires you to install FFmpeg software on your machine. In my case, I've found a way to use simple-hls without installing FFmpeg by using another package [@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg?activeTab=readme) and editing the package's node modules file `/node_modules/simple-hls/lib/index.js`.

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ls = (0, child_process_1.spawn)(ffmpegPath, commands)
```

When spawning the child_process, replace `'ffmpeg'` with the path of the FFmpeg installer from its npm package and it works fine.

Comment: I'm the person who wrote said NPM Module. Just commenting to say that it is awesome to officially be a "Stack Overflow Answer". Will be making some updates to it in the future.